# how to read gz file in R and convert the output into a proper data frame

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to read `dat.gz` file but the generated `dataframe` is very messed up, it has one column and thousands of rows, each row seems to have all the information with no tags or separation. does any body have an idea how to produce a proper data out of this file, as it should many columns with useful information. this is what I tried:

```
File_URL <- gzcon(url(paste('ftp://mirbase.org/pub/mirbase/CURRENT/miRNA.dat.gz')))

DATA_mir <- readLines(File_URL)

dat <- read.csv(textConnection(DATA_mir),sep="\t", header=T, comment.char="#",
                na.strings=".", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                quote="", fill=FALSE)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not in a clean tabular form, you'll have to parse it in a smart way.

```
$> zcat miRNA.dat.gz | head -n 20
ID   cel-let-7         standard; RNA; CEL; 99 BP.
XX
AC   MI0000001;
XX
DE   Caenorhabditis elegans let-7 stem-loop
XX
RN   [1]
RX   PUBMED; 11679671.
RA   Lau NC, Lim LP, Weinstein EG, Bartel DP;
RT   "An abundant class of tiny RNAs with probable regulatory roles in
RT   Caenorhabditis elegans";
RL   Science. 294:858-862(2001).
XX
RN   [2]
RX   PUBMED; 12672692.
RA   Lim LP, Lau NC, Weinstein EG, Abdelhakim A, Yekta S, Rhoades MW, Burge CB,
RA   Bartel DP;
RT   "The microRNAs of Caenorhabditis elegans";
RL   Genes Dev. 17:991-1008(2003).
XX
```

My guess is that this has been already done. Alternatively you could try [mirbase.db package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/mirbase.db.html).